# Where can I find the original brand names of every psychotropic medication?

Tags: mental-health, medications

I'm looking for a place to find the original (initial) brand name of every psychotropic medication when it was first introduced (internationally, not necessarily in the US).

I'm not interested in branded generics but I keep stumbling upon them everywhere I look.

Comment: Which places have you checked so far?

Comment: Just curious as to why you would need this?